# When will the Spark Cassandra connector with support for Spark 3.3 be released?

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark

Master branch has a merged [pull request](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/pull/1351) supporting Spark 3.3 how long before this gets built and published on maven repository?

Comment: This question should be asked not on StackOverflow but as comment on pull request or open issue in the connector repository. There are no rules on how long it will take to release new version, but it heavily depends on time availability of maintainers, their priorities, etc.

Comment: @AlexOtt I was linked here from their community https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra, and got there from github

Comment: anyway, the question about release timelines could be answered only by maintainers

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the project a bit, it appears that the project maintainers are awaiting to include support for Scala `2.13`.

See [here](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/pull/1351#issuecomment-1368908742) for the comment,

> *jtgrabowski commented Jan 2, 2023 7:33 AM EST - I asked the author for a followup, if there is no movement for a couple of days I'll release without 2.13 support.*

**tl;dr** -- wait for a couple additional days and you'll get the release or feel free to ping that PR if you need it immediately (as already suggested by Alexey Ott).

Comment: @RubberDuck, a new release is now made available by the project maintainers. See [here](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/releases/tag/v3.3.0) for the latest release. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

[Jaroslaw Grabovski](https://github.com/jtgrabowski) mentioned in [PR #1351](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/pull/1351) (for [SPARKC-693](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-693)) that the preference is to include support for Scala 2.13 in the new release.

I noted that Jaroslaw also reviewed [PR #1349](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/pull/1349) last week which provides support for Scala 2.13 ([SPARKC-686](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-686)) and requested some changes. [Marquis Wong](https://github.com/marquiswang) made the necessary updates to the PR over the weekend so it's up for review.

Provided it passes the tests, I envision both tickets will make it to the next release in the coming days. There is no scheduled ETA given it is an open-source project and subject to availability of community contributors.

For what it's worth, I've reached out to Jaroslaw and will update my answer if appropriate. Cheers!

**UPDATE Jan 14:** [Spark Cassandra connector 3.3](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector#version-compatibility) with support for Apache Spark 3.3 has been released.

---

Please support the Apache Cassandra community by hovering over the [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra) tag then click on the `Watch tag` button.  Thanks!

Comment: I am already building and using the library using master branch and didn't find a way to track maven releases. Your link will be helpful since it will indicate the new release. I am impressed the community is active and responsive.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Community contributors are usually more responsive but most were on a holiday break so responses in the last couple of weeks are a bit delayed. Cheers!